# $Q(y ,r):= \{z\in \mathbb{Z}^2: |z-y|_{\infty}<r\}$

Tags: calculus, analysis

> Consider $$Q(y ,r):= \{z\in \mathbb{Z}^2: |z-y|_{\infty}<r\}$$
>   What does his graph look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may look at this example from Wikipedia to better understand it

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#/media/File:Vector_norms.svg

Comment: Please, provide an answer, this belongs to the comment section and isn' t an answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is a square with length $2r$ centered at $y$; $|z-y|_\infty$ is in general defined as:

> $\sup_{n}{|z_n-y_n|}$

Where $z_n, y_n$ are the $n^{th}$ competent of $z,y$. So for your graph, it is simply a square

Comment: Is not it a rhombus center at $y$ with side $\sqrt{2}r$?

Comment: Sorry by bad, let me fix it

Comment: The side are $2r$